# Compare two json arrays in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following two `JSON` array objects.

questions.QuestionAlternatives:

```
[{
  Id: "53e169ce-acb1-4cb3-b7b9-9314a84660e0",
  AlternativeText: "Opt2",
  RiskScore: "1"
}, {
  Id: "a1c30d1f-e585-4a74-a3a5-9f2d26fb804f",
  AlternativeText: "Opt3",
  RiskScore: "2"
}, {
  Id: "85385ec6-a4d0-489b-bf08-b4a7321e9cfe",
  AlternativeText: "Opt1",
  RiskScore: "1"
}]
```

optionText:

```
[{
  OptionText = "Opt2", Id = "53e169ce-acb1-4cb3-b7b9-9314a84660e0"
}, {
  OptionText = "Opt3", Id = "a1c30d1f-e585-4a74-a3a5-9f2d26fb804f"
}, {
  OptionText = "Opt1", Id = "85385ec6-a4d0-489b-bf08-b4a7321e9cfe"
}, {
  OptionText = "opt5", Id = ""
}]
```

Now I want to compare this in the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json[0].Questions.length; i++) {
    if (json[0].Questions[i].Id == id) {
        //Compare here
    }
}
```

I want to check If the Id in optionText exists in QuestionAlternatives. If It does exist, I want to set the OptionText with the value from the OptionText inside optionText. A simple update.

If It does not exists, I want to add the object with the empty Id to the QuestionAlternative.

Anyone who can push me toward right direction?

I have tried this comparsion:

```
                for(var opt = 0; opt < optionText.length; opt++) {
                    for(var a = 0; a < json[0].Questions[i].QuestionAlternatives.length; a++) {
                        if(optionText[opt].Id ==  json[0].Questions[i].QuestionAlternatives[a].Id) {
                            console.log("exists");
                        } else {
                            console.log("does not");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But that gives me the following:

```
(3) exists
does not
(3) exists
does not
exists
```

Comment: that's not valid JSON

Comment: @nem035: Ok, but can you help me with my question?

Comment: Sure. The reason I said that was so you can give some actual data to work with :)

Comment: @nem035: No problem to work with data I've provided. :)

Comment: Loop first array then for each element loop through the second array and compare elements. What's the issue here?

Comment: Also try using a better naming convention. "If It does exist, I want to set the OptionText with the value from the OptionText inside optionText."

Comment: @taguenizy: The issue here Is how should I add the none-existing object? When the comparsion fails, I just got an undefined.

Comment: "If It does exist, I want to set the OptionText with the value from the OptionText inside optionText". This doesn't makes sense to me.

Comment: @LucasCosta: Check my updated question.

Comment: @taguenizy: Check my updated question with my comparsion.

Comment: In your comparison, where is the variable 'i' coming from? The outer loop is using the variable 'opt'.

Comment: @wackozacko: Check my question again and you will see where I want to do the comparsion. The comparsion Is inside antother loop

Comment: I see where your comparison is, but you're grabbing the object `json[0].Questions[i]` and `i` has not been declared as far as I can tell.

Comment: @wackozacko: As I said, read again: for (var i = 0; i < json[0].Questions.length; i++) {
    if (json[0].Questions[i].Id == id) {
        //Compare here
    }
}

Comment: @Bryan I apologize for the misunderstanding, I was referencing the comparison in your edit where you say _I have tried this comparsion:_. My recommendation is to ensure your JSON is valid and then check whether the Id exists in QuestionAlternatives using `array.filter` instead of another loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.NET. You can easily parse your json string to JArray and with for loop you can compare values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand, but here's how I would recommend you go about it in pseudo code.

```
for each object in optionText
  id = object.id
  filteredAlternatives = QuestionAlternatives.filter(question.id === id)
  if(filteredAlternatives.length > 0) 'Id in optionText exists in QuestionAlternatives!'
```

Look into [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object/hash-table to make this kind of operation more efficient (albeit making it a bit more memory intensive):

```
// var optionText = JSON.parse(...);
// questions.QuestionAlternatives = JSON.parse(...);

// questionAlternatives { Id => question alternative }
var questionAlternatives = {};
var questionAlternative;
for(var z = 0; z < questions.QuestionAlternatives.length; z++){
    questionAlternative = questions.QuestionAlternatives[z];
    questionAlternatives[questionAlternative.Id] = questionAlternative;
}

var option;
for(var z = 0; z < optionText.length; z++){
    option = optionText[z];
    if(questionAlternatives[option.Id]){
       // found alternative
       // something like this:
       questionAlternatives[option.Id].OptionText = option.OptionText;
    }else{
       // id not found on alternatives
    }
}
```